# Creating email form where user picks destination email and sends it from their own

Tags: php, html, css, forms, contact-form-7

I have no prior experience with PHP, but I'm trying to create a HTML email form which sends the message from the user's email address to a recipient that is selected from a dropdown menu.

HTML:

```html
    <form action="contact-form.php" method="post">
Which person would you like to contact?</strong><br>
<select name="person" size="1">
<option value="example1@me.com" selected>one</option>
<option value="example2@me.com">two</option>
<option value="example3@me.com">three</option>
<option value="example4@me.com">four</option>

<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="inquiry">
Message:<br>
<textarea name="Comments" rows="5" cols="42"></textarea><P>
Tell the donor how to get in touch with you:<br>
<p>
Name<input type="text" size="35" maxlength="256" name="realname"><br>
E-mail<input type="text" size="35" maxlength="256" name="UserEmail"><br>
Telephone<input type="text" size="35" maxlength="256" name="UserTel"><br>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php $recipient = $POST['person'];
$subject = "Contact Form";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$name = $_POST['realname'];
$email = $_POST['UserEmail'];
$telephone = $_POST['EserTel'];
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";?>
```

How can I be sure the email will be sent from the user's address? Is my setup for the dropdown going to work? I was hoping someone with more knowledge than I could take a quick look at this and give me feedback.

UPDATES:---------------------------------------------------

So to my understanding I have this a little closer thanks to all your help

This is my new PHP code, is this looking better?

```php
<?php  $sending = [
 ...
 1 => 'one@me.com',
 ...
 2 => 'two@me.com',
 ...
 3 => 'three@me.com',
 ...
 4 => 'four@me.com',
 ...
];
$subject = "Contact Form";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$name = $_POST['realname'];
$email = $_POST['UserEmail'];
$telephone = $_POST['UserTel'];
$headers = "From: ['realname'] <info@mywebaddress.com>\r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: This is not possible for a very good reason. It would mean that anyone could send an email from any address he wants to. Not a good idea, right?

Comment: The reason _why_ that is not possible: the email server you want to use to actually send the email will reject it. That is call prevention of relaying.

Answer (score 2):

You have three main issues.

The most obvious is that I can type anything in the "sender" field. I could use my real email - or any other.

A less immediately obvious problem is that you're sending to **the value of the 'person' select**. This too can be manipulated! You should rather have something like

```
 <option value="1">LSerni</option>
```

and then in the receiving code, an array

```
 $sending = [
     ...
     1 => 'lserni@gmail.com',
     ...
 ];
```

so that even if I *can* force a send of any number I like, if the number isn't in the $sending array, no mail gets generated.

The third problem is that you have no guarantees that the web server will be authorized by its mail relay to send emails on behalf of any John Doe. Chances are that it won't.

Even then, the email from "john@somewhere.foo" might be sent from a domain with DKIM and/or SFP security policies, which will make any sender machine *except the registered somewhere.foo MX* - which your server *isn't* - prohibited and marked as spam source:

```
 (from "john@mail.baz" to "joe@mail.foo")
 webserver.bar      mail.bar                           mail.foo       joe@mail.foo
 YOUR SERVER ---> ITS MAIL RELAY --> ... --> ... --> RCPT SERVER ----> USER
                   |                                  |                  |
                  refuses to send                refuses to receive      |
                  except @mail.bar              except from @mail.bar    |
                                                                         |
                                   marks as spam ------------------------+
```

All in all, you will have better include the user's email as a text content in the email, and the email itself be sent with **the web server's default allowed email address** (ask your Web server's maintainer or ISP for details).

(Another easier possibility is to use a `mailto:` link: this offloads everything to the reader's systems and his mail own, familiar mail program).

Comment: I'd add, instead of setting the `From` header to the user-provided address, set the `Reply-To` header to it. This won't trigger SPF/DKIM but the recipient's email client app will still behave as if the sender created the message directly.

Comment: Thank you folks so much. Is the php I added to the question better?